# which she couldn't (do)

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

An article titled "[A year spent without shopping](https://www.treehugger.com/culture/year-spent-without-shopping.html)" has this paragraph:

> McGagh told the interviewer that her challenge got tough as the first few months of 2016 arrived, post-holiday season. The novelty had worn off and the days were short and dark; nobody in London wants to do much except sit in the pub, **which she couldn't do** because that costs money.

In the last sentence, can you leave out "do" as follows?

> nobody in London wants to do much except sit in the pub, **which she couldn't** because that costs money.

Comment: Yes, you can.  The sentence doesn't feel quite as *complete* as the version in the article, but it's fine.

Comment: It doesn't feel right without "do" because, strictly speaking, the couldn't  then refers to the main verb "wants" and the whole sentence doesn't make much sense until you mentally adjust the grammar.

Comment: @smatterer Why would "couldn't" without "do" refer to the main verb "wants" in the first place, when "couldn't do" can easily mean "couldn't sit in the pub"?